# Application Error while installing wamp server

Tags: wampserver

i was trying to install the wamp server 2.2 intended for a 64-bit OS.. there's an application error saying "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application." But when i went to Mozilla Firefox to go to the localhost, it won't open. please help me..

Answer (score 1):

If the application didn't start correctly you can't expect for localhost to work. Be sure you installed the 64 bit version on a 64bit OS or you can try xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Application error The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) The error code means "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT"

I know 2 possible reason for this:

1- In most cases this error occurred when 64 bit windows reaches 32 bit dll in search path. Specially in this case and about wamp server 64 bit it can be caused by 32 bit version of msvcr100.dll in path. Just download 64 bit version of it and copy the file to "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin"
here you can download the 64 bit of this dll http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100
After this click on wamp icon in system tray Apache/Service/install service to fix the problem.

2- the exe file is damaged due to disk error. In this case try using fdisk. if fdisk found errors on disk and problem not fixed then reinstall the program.

Comment: In his answer he says copy file to "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin" while this problem seems associated with install and not with starting.

Comment: Its wampserver 2.2 problem. I faced this during install, googled it and finally after solving it in described way I posted the answer. The error can be ignored but wamp server wont start correctly after install... @ArvindK.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the windows version mismatches. Uninstall Wamp Server 2.2 and download Wamp Server 64bit version.

[Download](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#wampserver-64-bits-apache-2-4)